# Debug Assertion Failed

Tags: c++, runtime, runtime-error

I am doing a nodejs addon. The code bellow is a part of the last routine that make speech recognition:

```
char * resultado = Julius[cliente_id].NotifyCallbackLoop("random");
float cm = Julius[cliente_id].ReturnCM();
Julius[cliente_id].~SREngineJulius();
cout << "End Recognition - Client -->" << cliente_id << endl;

// create a ISO-8859-1 a.k.a. Latin1 string
const uint8_t* octets = reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t*>(result);
Local<String> devolve = String::NewFromOneByte(isolate, octets);


Local<Number> num = Number::New(isolate, cm);

Local<Object> obj = Object::New(isolate);
obj->Set(String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "cm"), num);          
obj->Set(String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "recog"), devolve);   //C++--->JS
args.GetReturnValue().Set(obj);
```

If `result` are small words like "home", this will work just fine, for many users the server has. But if the word is bigger, like "signal-processing-laboratory" the server will crash in the addon. After the debugging, I conclude the addon will run without problems until `"End Recognition - Client -->"`. And then this error appears:

> Debug Assertion Failed!
> File: f:\vctools\crt\crtw32\misc\dbgheap.c
> Line: 1322
>
> Expression: _CrtIsValidHeapPointer(pUserData)

Comment: You shouldn't explicitly call the destructor of `SREngineJulius`.

Comment: @molbdnilo I am doing to free the memory that `SREngineJulius` needs. Like, acoustic models, language models etc. Any alternative? Anyway, I will tray without destructor.

Comment: The alternative is to not do it. The destructor is called automatically when the object's lifetime ends. Explicitly calling it causes it to be called twice, which has undefined behaviour.

Comment: So @molbdnilo , if I "reuse" one object `SREngineJulius`the desctructor is called automatically, or the new parameters replace the old ones?

Comment: "reuse"? Are you creating them using placement-new? (If you're just assigning a new value, it's your responsibility to ensure that the assignment operator does the Right Thing.)

Comment: Just like that as global: `SREngineJulius Julius[some int value];` and them the client.id (typeof=number), is passed by nodejs. My idea is to loop between index of `SREngineJulius`

Answer (score 0):

As @molbdino says, the destructor will cause problems. Removing it, will solve the "Debug Assertion Failed".